# amChart total values of graphics

Tags: amcharts

I want to write all of the total values in some where in graphics. My graphics may be column or stacked chart. How can I calculate all summ values in data and write?

```
"dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 2025
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809
  } ]
```

Or stacked data

```
"dataProvider": [{
            "year": 2003,
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5,
            "asia": 2.1,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.2,
            "africa": 0.1
        }, {
            "year": 2004,
            "europe": 2.6,
            "namerica": 2.7,
            "asia": 2.2,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.3,
            "africa": 0.1
        }, {
            "year": 2005,
            "europe": 2.8,
            "namerica": 2.9,
            "asia": 2.4,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.3,
            "africa": 0.1
        }]
```

- [Column chart](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)
- [Stacked chart](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

Or is it possible to write in legend like this: `"General Sum: 1254"`

Comment: I'm assuming these are AmCharst demos? You need to click save in order to link the fiddles generated by the AmCharts demos. Alternatively, just link to the AmCharts demos on the website directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`totalText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#totalText) in the value axis to generate a sum of the stack:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  valueAxes: [{
    // ...
    totalText: "Total: [[total]]"
  }],
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ca7z8uoj/)

For single columns, try [`periodValueText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#periodValueText) in the legend.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  legend: {
    // ...
    periodValueText: "Selection total: [[value.sum]]"
  }
  // ...
});
```

Note this shows the sum of the columns in selected period/zoom for a particular graph.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nbgbwvr/)