# Adding total label for column to stacked chart (xy chart)

Tags: amcharts

I am coding my first amcharts4 stacked chart from this example https://www.amcharts.com/demos/100-stacked-column-chart/ but I have a problem with adding the total label above every column (total like simple sum of values, not percentages).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjiwe.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to create a `LabelBullet` on the last, stacked series, position it outside of the chart, e.g. `dy = -20`.

To get it to be visible outside the chart, set `chart.maskBullets = false`, otherwise it'll get clipped.

To display totals, make sure to have the relevant axis calculate them in advance e.g. via `valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;` (this only available for stacked series). Then on the label's `text`, use the [`.total` placeholder](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Placeholders_for_numeric_values), in the demo below it'd be `labelBullet.label.text = {valueY.total};`.

Sample code:

```js
// Enable .total and .totalPercent placeholders for stacked series
valueAxis.calculateTotals = true;

// Allow labels to show beyond chart area
chart.maskBullets = false;

// Create a LabelBullet for the top, stacked series
var labelBullet = series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
var label = labelBullet.label;
label.text = "{valueY.total}";
label.dy = -20;
```

Below is a fork of our [100% Stacked Column Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/100-stacked-column-chart/) with the above code:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/c06396113836bb29024713d8bac5c883

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of demo]

In this fork I've disabled the scrollbar for convenience. If you enable it, remember to shift it upwards, too, e.g. `chart.scrollbarX.dy = -25;`. Otherwise it'll overlay the `LabelBullet`s.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be `totalText` you can use to achieve exactly what you want in `amchart3`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722320/2410655, but I don't know if it would be available in `amchart4`.

To workaround, my idea is to have 2 `CategoryAxis` and they're opposite of each other, and have one of the `CategoryAxis` to display the totals of each category.

#### Change of your data

You need to include a data field for the totals of each category. You can calculate that and add it to the data either manually, or with JavaScript loops:

```
let data = [
  {
    category: "One",
    value1: 1,
    value2: 5,
    value3: 3,
    total: 9
  },
  {
    category: "Two",
    value1: 2,
    value2: 5,
    value3: 3,
    total: 10
  },
  {
    category: "Three",
    value1: 3,
    value2: 5,
    value3: 4,
    total: 12
  },
  {
    category: "Four",
    value1: 4,
    value2: 5,
    value3: 6,
    total: 15
  },
  {
    category: "Five",
    value1: 3,
    value2: 5,
    value3: 4,
    total: 12
  },
  {
    category: "Six",
    value1: 2,
    value2: 13,
    value3: 1,
    total: 16
  }
];
```

#### Add another opposite Category xAxis

The trick here to display the total is to have another category axis on the opposite position, and use `adapter` to change its label to display the total numbers:

```
let chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
    data: data,
    ...,
    xAxes: [{
        type: "CategoryAxis",
        dataFields: {
            category: "category"
        },
        ...
    }, {
        type: "CategoryAxis",
        dataFields: {
            category: "category"
        },
        renderer: {
            ...,
            opposite: true,
            labels: {
                adapter: {
                    text: function(label, target, key) {
                        return "Total: {total}";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    ...
}, "chart", am4charts.XYChart);
```

I had tried to have another category axis to display `total` directly, like:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: "CategoryAxis",
    dataFields: {
        category: "category"
    },
    ...
}, {
    type: "CategoryAxis",
    dataFields: {
        category: "total"
    },
    ...
}]
```

That failed because category axis automatically merged duplicates (for example, total 12 from category "Three" and "Five") and resulted in missing numbers.

#### Result

[image]

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/aq9Laaew/297155/